# google sheets make data validations select todays year/month/week on open

Tags: google-sheets

I have three data validation boxes that are populated with Year, Month, and Week, I would like to be able to have them all automatically select today's Year, Month and Week when the spreadsheet is opened.. I have googled and googled for an answer to this and have come to no avail... I've added an image of the validation boxes below. The cell numbers are A5, B5, C5.

[validation boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Rkf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. It ended up being relatively simple.

```
function onOpen(e) {
var year = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "YYYY"); 
var month = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MMMM");
var week = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "'Week 'ww");
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Weekly").getRange("A5").setValue(year);
Utilities.sleep(3000);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Weekly").getRange("B5").setValue(month);
Utilities.sleep(3000);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Weekly").getRange("C5").setValue(week);}
```

Comment: how do I make it so the starting day is Monday and not Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) `onOpen(e)` to activate a script to populate your three cells with the elements of "today's"  date.

If your attempt does not work you would probably find extra help here. once you show how far you have reached and what went wrong, where.